# Why gdb backtrace syscall address is different from syscall table address

Tags: linux, gdb, system-calls

I'm really confusing with syscall address.

1 now I hook a syscall(fake_sendto) replace real syscall(sct[__NR_sendto]), and it workes normally.

```
    # define fm_alert(fmt, ...) fm_printk(KERN_ALERT, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

    void
    print_ascii(void *addr, size_t count, const char *prompt)
    {
        size_t index;

        fm_alert("%s:\n", prompt);

        for (index = 0; index < count; index += 1) {
            pr_cont("%c", *((unsigned char *)addr + index));
        }

        return;
    }

    asmlinkage long
    fake_sendto(int fd, void __user *buff, size_t len, unsigned flags,
                struct sockaddr __user *addr, int addr_len)
    {
        void *kbuf = kmalloc(len + 1, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (kbuf != NULL) {
            if (copy_from_user(kbuf, buff, len)) {
                fm_alert("%s\n", "copy_from_user failed.");
            } else {
                if (memcmp(kbuf, "GET", 3) == 0 ||
                    memcmp(kbuf, "POST", 4) == 0) {
                    print_ascii(kbuf, len, "ascii");
                }
            }
            kfree(kbuf);
        } else {
            fm_alert("%s\n", "kmalloc failed.");
        }

        fm_alert("hook:%p, orig:%p\n", fake_sendto, real_sendto);
        return real_sendto(fd, buff, len, flags, addr, addr_len);
    }
```

now I dmesg to show logs:

```
    [ 3466.057815] ifmonko.fake_sendto: hook:ffffffffc06d9070, orig:ffffffff8156b2c0
```

ok, I think the truely sys_sento address is above 0xffffffff8156b2c0

but when I write a test program, gdb print sendto function address is 0x7ffff7b11400 ! 
see below gdb debug info:

```
    (gdb) disas main
    Dump of assembler code for function main:
       ...
       0x0000000000400cb4 <+743>:   callq  0x400810 <sendto@plt>
       ...
    End of assembler dump.
    (gdb) b *0x0000000000400cb4
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x400cb4: file ser.c, line 89.
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /home/lid/ser 9898
    Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400cb4 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe6d8) at ser.c:89
    89          nwrite = sendto(sfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0,
    (gdb) c
    Continuing.

    Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400cb4 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe6d8) at ser.c:89
    89          nwrite = sendto(sfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0,
    (gdb) p sendto
    $1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7b11400 <sendto>
    (gdb) si
    0x0000000000400810 in sendto@plt ()
    (gdb) 
    sendto () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
    81  T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
    (gdb) bt
    #0  sendto () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
    #1  0x0000000000400cb9 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe6d8) at ser.c:89
    (gdb) disas
    Dump of assembler code for function sendto:
    => 0x00007ffff7b11400 <+0>: cmpl   $0x0,0x2c8b6d(%rip)        # 0x7ffff7dd9f74 <__libc_multiple_threads>
       0x00007ffff7b11407 <+7>: jne    0x7ffff7b1141c <sendto+28>
       0x00007ffff7b11409 <+0>: mov    %rcx,%r10
       0x00007ffff7b1140c <+3>: mov    $0x2c,%eax
       0x00007ffff7b11411 <+8>: syscall 
       0x00007ffff7b11413 <+10>:    cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
       0x00007ffff7b11419 <+16>:    jae    0x7ffff7b1144f <sendto+79>
       0x00007ffff7b1141b <+18>:    retq   
       0x00007ffff7b1141c <+28>:    sub    $0x8,%rsp
       0x00007ffff7b11420 <+32>:    callq  0x7ffff7b1df20 <__libc_enable_asynccancel>
       0x00007ffff7b11425 <+37>:    mov    %rax,(%rsp)
       0x00007ffff7b11429 <+41>:    mov    %rcx,%r10
       0x00007ffff7b1142c <+44>:    mov    $0x2c,%eax
       0x00007ffff7b11431 <+49>:    syscall 
       0x00007ffff7b11433 <+51>:    mov    (%rsp),%rdi
       0x00007ffff7b11437 <+55>:    mov    %rax,%rdx
       0x00007ffff7b1143a <+58>:    callq  0x7ffff7b1df80 <__libc_disable_asynccancel>
       0x00007ffff7b1143f <+63>:    mov    %rdx,%rax
       0x00007ffff7b11442 <+66>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
       0x00007ffff7b11446 <+70>:    cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
       0x00007ffff7b1144c <+76>:    jae    0x7ffff7b1144f <sendto+79>
       0x00007ffff7b1144e <+78>:    retq   
       0x00007ffff7b1144f <+79>:    mov    0x2c2a12(%rip),%rcx        # 0x7ffff7dd3e68
       0x00007ffff7b11456 <+86>:    neg    %eax
       0x00007ffff7b11458 <+88>:    mov    %eax,%fs:(%rcx)
    ---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
       0x00007ffff7b1145b <+91>:    or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
       0x00007ffff7b1145f <+95>:    retq   
    End of assembler dump.
    (gdb)
```

why does gdb show different from between hook function and syscall table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why does gdb show different from between hook function and syscall table ?

One is in the kernel space, and the other is in user space. They have approximately *nothing* to do with each other.